# Angular http get returns empty array

Tags: angular, http

To update the data, I have to call the getProduct() which returns an empty array

```
getProduct() {
        return this.httpObj.get(`${this.uri}/products`);
    }
```

below is ngonit() of updateproduct.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.router.params.subscribe(params =>{
          this.id=+params['id'];
       });
       this.productService.getProduct().subscribe((data:Response)=>this.products=data.json());
       console.log(this.data)
  //console displays empty array

  }
```

Comment: move the `console.log` to the `subscribe` method and add the output to the question.

Comment: Whats the response when you try `${this.uri}/products` from browser or postman?

Answer (score 0):

Please do this, console log inside your subscription

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.router.params.subscribe(params =>{
          this.id=+params['id'];
       });

      this.productService.getProduct().subscribe((data:Response)=>{
           this.products=data.json();
           console.log(this.products)
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

** First check the response you are getting and its better to check API's over Postman or rest client before implementing. **

```
     ngOnInit() {
               this.router.params.subscribe(params =>{
                  this.id=+params['id'];
               });
               this.productService.getProduct().subscribe(
    (data:Response)=>
this.products=data.json()
     console.log("responsedata",data)
    );

          }
```